# How to commit to another branch without checking it out?

Tags: git

Is it possible to commit changes to another branch without checking it out?

Otherwise I always have to checkout my branch first and commit to it, which causes the deployment to run and revert everything to match the checked out branch.

Is there a command to commit directly into the branch e.g.

```
git commit --branch='my_target_branch' -m "commit description" -m "more details"
```

Comment: I honestly don't know. I wonder if @torek might.

Comment: *"which causes the deployment to run"* -- this is where the trouble is. You should not deploy from your development repository but from a clone (preferably bare). The deployment can be triggered manually, by a Git hook when you push or by a cron job that runs often enough.